# Installing Highcharts plugins in webpack?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reactjs, webpack

How does one use Highcharts plugins in webpack/npm? I'm using [react-highcharts](http://kirjs.github.io/react-highcharts/) and I want to use a few plugins, but there's no docs anywhere telling you how to mix these two together. I've tried downloading the plugin, taking the .js file and putting it in the same folder as my current .js files, and requiring it (in the .js file that's using a highchart), as follows:

```js
require('./yaxis-panning.js');
```

But surprisingly, that doesn't work. Is it even possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Maybe plugin is included before Highcharts package?